# name followed by :: must be a class or namespace but header defined

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to implement some methods that have been declared in my header file in my source file.

I keep getting this error

```
name followed by :: must be a class or namespace
```

and from searching it seems like a project setup error, however both my files are in the correct directory.

**main**

```
#include "sarray.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class genericData>
sarray::sarray(int size)
{
    if (size > 0) genericData data = new int[size];
    else {
        cout << "illegal array size = " << size << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
template<class genericData>
sarray::~sarray()
{
    delete[] data;
}
template<class genericData>
int& sarray::operator[](int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= size) {
        cout << "index " << i << " is out of bounds." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return data[i];
}
int main()
{
    // create a 10-element safe array
    sarray myArray = sarray(10);
    sarray array(10);
    // in-bound access, [] is used on the left side or an assignment
    array[5] = 23;
    // in-bound access, [] is used on the right side of an operation
    cout << array[5] << endl;
    // out-of-bound accesses
    array[13] = 392;
    cout << array[-1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**sarray.h**

```
#ifndef SARRAYS_H
#define SARRAYS_H

template<class genericData>
class sarray {
public:
    sarray(int size);
    ~sarray();
    & operator[](int i);
private:
    int size;
    genericData* data;
};
#endif // !sarrays
```

Comment: `& operator[](int i);` in `sarray.h` should be `int& operator[](int i);` .  Is that a copy paste error or is that in your actual code?

Comment: You left out the template parameter on your definitions; the class is `sarray<genericData>`. Look more closely at examples. (And this is the one situation where meaningless one-character names like `T` are preferred to something more descriptive.)

Comment: Usually you should put the implementation of the class template functions in the header. But that's not the issue here.

Comment: `genericData data = new int[size];` should probably be `data = new genericData[size];`

Comment: Also, read about "the rule of three" as soon as you possibly can.

Comment: @JHBonarius What is the issue here then?

Comment: @LyraOrwell The issue is what I mentioned about the template parameter. (I'm voting to close this as a typo.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your member function implementations need the template parameter too:

  ```
  template<class genericData>
  sarray<genericData>::sarray(...) ...
  ```
- Put the implementation of the class template member functions in the header file as well. If you don't *nothing* will be generated in the object file when you compile the `.cpp` file. The compiler wouldn't know for which types you want the methods instantiated.
- Don't use `using namespace std;` - especially not in the global scope in header files. It forces the usage onto every user of your header file.
- Since your class owns a resource that can't be safely copied or moved using the default copy/move constructors, `delete` those.
- Don't `exit()` in bounds-checking functions. Throw the `out_of_range` exception.
- Use an unsigned integer for array sizes, like `size_t`.
- When using your class template, you need to supply the type you'd like to store in it.

Example:

```
#ifndef SARRAYS_H
#define SARRAYS_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<class genericData>
class sarray {
public:
    sarray(size_t size);
    sarray(const sarray&) = delete; // copying deleted
    sarray(sarray&&) = delete;      // moving deleted
    ~sarray();
    genericData& operator[](size_t i);

private:
    size_t size;
    genericData* data;
};

template<class genericData>
sarray<genericData>::sarray(size_t size) : // use the member initializer list
    size(size),                            
    data(new genericData[size])
{}

template<class genericData>
sarray<genericData>::~sarray() {
    delete[] data;
}

template<class genericData>
genericData& sarray<genericData>::operator[](size_t i) {
    if (i >= size) throw std::out_of_range(std::to_string(i));
    return data[i];
}

#endif
```

```
#include "sarray.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create a 10-element safe array
    sarray<int> myArray = sarray<int>(10);
    sarray<int> array(10);
    // in-bound access, [] is used on the left side or an assignment
    array[5] = 23;
    // in-bound access, [] is used on the right side of an operation
    cout << array[5] << endl;
    // out-of-bound accesses
    array[13] = 392;

    cout << array[-1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small issue: You (and OP) do not store `size` in the constructor.

Comment: @Frodyne Good spotting - fixed :-)